# $i$-th singular value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is stated in the book *Matrix Analysis by R. Horn* (p. 453),

> Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. Let $A = V\Lambda W^{*}$ where $\Lambda = diag\{\sigma_{1}, \ldots, \sigma_{n}\}$ contains singular values of
>   $A$ and $W = [w_{1}, \ldots,w_{n}]$. Then 
>   $$ \sigma_{i}(A) = \min\{\|Ax\| | x\in span\{w_{1}, \ldots w_{i}\}, \; \|x\|=1  \}. $$

I would like to prove this theorem.

My try is:

Considering $A = V\Lambda W^{*}$ we have

\begin{align}
\min_{\qquad\|x\| = 1, \\ x\in span\{w_{1}, \ldots w_{i}\}} \|Ax\| &= \min_{\qquad\|x\| = 1, \\ x\in span\{w_{1}, \ldots w_{i}\}} \|V\Lambda W^{*}x\| \\
&= \min_{\qquad\|x\| = 1, \\ x\in span\{w_{1}, \ldots w_{i}\}} \|\Lambda W^{*}x\|\\
&= \min_{\qquad\|y\| = 1, \\ x\in span\{w_{1}, \ldots w_{i}\}} \|\Lambda y\|\\
\end{align}
where $y=Wx$.

Now, I am not sure how to continue in a rigorous manner.

- Can you give me a hint to continue if my approach is correct?
- The $\min$ here should not be $\max$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if $x=\sum_i c_i w_i$ then $Ax=\sum_i c_i \sigma_i u_i$. By the orthogonality you have $\| Ax \|^2 = \sum_i |c_i|^2 \sigma_i^2$, and by the unit assumption about $x$ you have that $\sum_i |c_i|^2=1$. Thus $\| Ax \|^2$ is a convex combination of the $\sigma_i^2$. Can you finish now?

Comment: How can we conclude that: $\min \|Ax\|=\sigma_i$?

Comment: @math14 Well, $\| Ax \|^2 \geq \sigma_i^2$ under these assumptions (just replace all the other $\sigma_j^2$ by $\sigma_i^2$ and use $\sum |c_i|^2=1$). So that gives you a bound. How can you attain that bound?

Comment: Thanks @Ian: then, for $c = [0, \ldots, 0,1]^{t}$ we have $\|Ax\| = \sigma_{i}$. Is it your point?

Comment: @math14 Yes (the $i$th entry being 1).